# Calculate the minimum starting from today (excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to get excel 2013 to display the minimum for a structured table but only from rows that are dated today or after.

The table is a standard structured table, and most of the formulas I have been using use the [@[column] designation for targeting.

in the column called `date` I have hand typed dates, excel will work with them as serial dates for math and I have used `today()` in a few of those for calculating how many days have passed between entries (daily interest calculation if you were interested)

This is an example of what most of the spreadsheet formulas look like and I've been at this for hours, lots of manual data entry.

```
=IF([@DESCRIPTION]="mortgage",IF(([@DATE]-B236<1),P236-[@[Paid on card]]-[@[Paid from Savings]],(((([@DATE]-B236)*0.001367)*P236)+P236-[@[Paid on card]]-[@[Paid from Savings]])),IF(([@DATE]-B236<1),P236,(((([@DATE]-B236)*0.001367)*P236)+P236)))
```

which is basically if the transaction is labelled mortgage, then calculate the current balance from the last balance and if it has been at least one day since the last entry then add daily interest for however many days since the last balance entry minus payments made from card or from savings if not then just calculate the last balance and add any interest as appropriate.

I need to know the lowest value for column "account balance" but only in rows whose date is `>today()` and I cant for the life of me work out a way to get this to happen.

I am thinking something life `IF(min"where[@[date]]-today()>1")` but that reads more like TSQL than something excel will accept.

or `=WHERE([@[date]]-today()>1,MIN`

If there is a non VBA solution I would prefer it, but if not, I'll use a VBA solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-structured example that you can adapt to your needs.  Say we have dates in column **A** from **A2** to **A24** and values in column **B** and we want the minimum value in column **B** for dates greater or equal to today's date.

Use the *Array Formula*:

```
=MIN(IF(A2:A24>=TODAY(),B2:B24))
```

For example:

[image]

*Array formulas* must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same formula as Gary's Student supplied using structured references:

```
=MIN(IF(Table1[Date]>=TODAY(),Table1[Value]))
```

Again, this is an array formula, and must be confirmed by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`